# I can disable the default buttons to minimize and close the entire wpf application window?

Tags: wpf, xaml, prism

I can't disable the default window close and minimize buttons of a user control using IDialogService

IDialogService won't let me disable the default window buttons. I am using wpf with prism. Is there a way to disable these buttons by default, since the IDialogService creates them by default in a usercontrol.

Comment: you can customize the window the dialog service uses